# Loop through matrix in R and calculate measurement difference between all users

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix, match

I have a matrix that is 10 rows by 4 columns. Each row represents a user, and each column a measurement. Some users only have one measurement, while others may have the full 4 measurements.

The goals I want to accomplish with this matrix are three fold:

1. To subtract the user's measurements from their own measurements (across columns);
2. To subtract the user's measurement from other user's measurement points (all included, across rows);
3. To create a final matrix that counts the number of "matches" (comparisons) each user has against themselves and others.

Within a threshold of **2.0** units, I have tried to measure each user's measurement against their own measurement and other users by obtaining the difference with a nested for-loop.

Below is an example of what the `clean_data` matrix looks like, and this matrix was used for all three goals:

```
        M1      M2      M3      M4       
  U1    148.2   148.4   155.6   155.7
  U2    149.5   150.1   150.1   153.9
  U3    148.4   154.2   NA      NA
  U4    154.5   NA      NA      NA         
  U5    151.1   156.9   157.1   NA
```

For Goal #3, the **output** should look something akin to this matrix:

```
        U1    U2    U3    U4    U5
   U1   2     8     4     2     3
   U2   8     3     2     1     4
   U3   4     2     0     1     0
   U4   2     1     1     0     0
   U5   3     4     0     0     1
```

For example: User 1 has **2** matches with themselves because, with all 4 of their measurements, 2 differences were less than a value of 2.0 units. User 1 also has **8** matches with *User 2*. Each of User 1's measurements were subtracted iteratively from User 2's measurements (stored as an absolute value), and those differences that were below a value of 2 were considered a "match."

I have tried using the following nested for-loop, however I believe it is only counting the number of elements in my matrix instead of adding the differences.

```
# Set the time_threshold.

time_threshold <- 2.000

# Create an empty matrix the same dimensions as the number of users present.
matrix_a<-matrix(nrow = nrow(clean_data), ncol = nrow(clean_data))

# Use a nested for-loop to calculate the intra-user 
# and inter-user time differences, adding values below 
# the threshold up for those user-comparisons.

for (i in 1:nrow(clean_data)) {
  for (j in 1:nrow(clean_data)) {
    matrix_a[i, j] <-
      round(sum(!is.na(abs((clean_data[i, 2:dim(clean_data)[2]]) -
                             (clean_data[j, 2:dim(clean_data)[2]])
      ) <= time_threshold)) / 2)
  }
}
 
# Dividing by 2 and rounding has proven that this code only counts the 
# number of vectors that are not NA, not the values below by time_threshold (2.000).
```

Is there a way that can calculate the differences I outlined above, and is also more efficient than a nested for-loop?

***Note:*** *The structure of these data are only relevant in so far that differences can be calculated for individuals across rows and columns. Missing values in this example are represented as NA, and should **not** be included in the calculation. Alternatively, I have set them to -0.01, which still has not changed the outcome of my for-loop.*

Comment: Can you explain the logic of how you go from input to output? What are the calculations that you perform?

Comment: From the first matrix (input), I take the individual element, subtract by other elements in remaining rows and columns. For example, M1U1 (148.2) - M1U2 (149.5), then M1U1 (148.2) - M2U1 (148.4). The absolute value of these differences are taken. All NAs should be excluded from these calculations. If the difference is <= 2.0 units, that is considered a "match" (+1). The second matrix is the output, where all matches are summed. The rounding and division is superfluous, was just for a sanity check to see if I was actually getting the differences (which in the current for-loop I am not).

Comment: I'm confused as to how "User 1 also has 8 matches with User 2. " when User 1 only has 4 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a function to do the loop for you:

```
fun <- function(index, dat){
  i <- index[1]
  j <- index[2]
  m <- if(i==j) combn(dat[i,],2, function(x)diff(x))
   else do.call("-", expand.grid(dat[i, ], dat[j, ]))
  sum(abs(m)<2, na.rm = TRUE)
}

dist_fun <- function(dat){
  dat <- as.matrix(dat)
  result <- diag(0, nrow(dat))
  mat_index <- which(lower.tri(result, TRUE), TRUE)
  result[mat_index] <- apply(mat_index, 1, fun, dat = dat)
  result[mat_index[,2:1]] <- result[mat_index]
  result
}

dist_fun(df)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    2    8    4    2    4
[2,]    8    3    4    1    3
[3,]    4    4    0    1    0
[4,]    2    1    1    0    0
[5,]    4    3    0    0    1
```

Comment: Thank Onyambu. What is `index`, does that refer to the dimensions of the data? And why are you calling only the first and second items of index?

Comment: @JoshuaMorriss index is the indices of the data. eg 1,2 meaning first row and second row.  1,3 1st row and 3rd row etc. I am only interested in 1,2 and not 2,1 since they are both the same. Also index has only two numbers in it your are working with dataframes/matrices. Try and see whether you can understand each element of the code

Answer (score 2):

Here's one tidyverse approach. I convert the data to longer format, then join it to itself by User (across) and by time point (down), each time counting the number of matches. Then I combine the two and convert to wide format again.

```
library(tidyverse)
my_data2 <- my_data %>% pivot_longer(-User)

left_join(my_data2, my_data2, by = "User") %>%
  filter(name.x < name.y, abs(value.y - value.x) <= 2) %>%   # EDIT
  count(User) %>%
  select(User.x = User, User.y = User, n) -> compare_across

my_data3 <- my_data2 %>% mutate(dummy = 1)                   # EDIT
inner_join(my_data3, my_data3, by = "dummy") %>%             # EDIT
  filter(abs(value.x - value.y) <=2, User.x != User.y) %>%
  count(User.x, User.y) -> compare_down

bind_rows(compare_across, compare_down) %>%
  arrange(User.x, User.y) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = User.y, values_from = n, values_fill = list(n = 0))


# A tibble: 5 x 6
  User.x    U1    U2    U3    U4    U5
  <chr>  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 U1         2     8     4     2     4
2 U2         8     3     4     1     3
3 U3         4     4     0     1     0
4 U4         2     1     1     0     0
5 U5         4     3     0     0     1
```

---

source data:

```
my_data <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
              User = c("U1", "U2", "U3", "U4", "U5"),
                M1 = c(148.2, 149.5, 148.4, 154.5, 151.1),
                M2 = c(148.4, 150.1, 154.2, NA, 156.9),
                M3 = c(155.6, 150.1, NA, NA, 157.1),
                M4 = c(155.7, 153.9, NA, NA, NA)
)
```

Comment: The output is not the same as the one posted by OP. This doesn't produce the desired output

Comment: Thanks for the correction -- I had misread the OP and hadn't realized how the result led from the q.